# access a function inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I know this has been mentioned multiple times, but I can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

**Index.html code.**

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>myPage</title>
    <script src="libs/h5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="content" width="1025" height="670">
      <iframe id="homePage" src="pages/homepage.html" width="1025" height="670" seamless></iframe>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**h5.js code**

```
function setTextHidden()
{
       <------------ **How do I call the hideText function inside the iframe from the parent?**
}
```

**js code for homepage.html in iframe**

```
function hideText()
{
   console.log("hideText");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`window.frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.frames) property to access the `window` object of your iFrame, from which you can call `hideText`:

```
function setTextHidden() {
    window.frames[0].hideText(); // assuming this is the first iframe on your page
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error when I try the above.  Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URLfile:///C:/Users/admin/Documents/HTML5/pages/home.html from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/admin/Documents/HTML5/index.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match. h5.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: Property 'hideText' of object [object global] is not a function

Comment: window.frames[0].hideText() works perfectly in ie, firefox, and safari.  I can't figure out how to get it to work in Chrome.

Comment: I figured out that the error I was receiving was due to something else.   window.frames[0].hideText() is working perfectly in Chrome.  Thanks